# How to detect if an integer is two-digit or not in pascal. (no functions

Tags: integer, numbers, pascal, freepascal, modulo

How can I use mod, or div, to detect if a given positive integer is a two-tigit one?
For instance, if the given number is 23 it will shows a message saying 'Two-digit number'
But if the number is 230 it will show 'Not a two-digit number'
NOTE: I HAVE TO USE ONLY SIMPLE COMMANDS - NO FUNCTIONS

Let's say the given number is 77
I tried doing 77 mod 10
But it didn't work for all the number
What should I do?

Comment: `InRange(x, 10, 99)`  note that I'm not sure how or if you want to handle negative numbers

Comment: If anybody suggests converting to a string I will cry

Comment: Without function call, `if  (x < 100) and (x >= 10)` or `if ((x div 100) < 10) and ((x div 10) > 0)`

Comment: why would you perform a divide @LURD or indeed two

Comment: I know that a integer division is not the fastest thing on earth. The question asks for a solution using `mod` or `div` though. And not a function call.

Comment: If you can't call a function then yes it's back to comparison operators

Comment: This is your [2nd question with the "no functions" requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74657922/4299358) and it also sounds like a homework task. You will not learn if you outsource the assignments.

Comment: It's not homework, I am just really familiar with other languages and before going deep into pascal, I need to learn the basics to understand it better. It's not that nowadays a lot of people use pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just `div`:

```
if ((x div 100) < 1) and ((x div 10) >= 1) then
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the integer is a positive number and not using a function call :

```
if  (x < 100) and (x >= 10) then ... // 2 - digit postive number
```

Comment: Probably more idiomatic for Pascal: `if x in [10..99] then`